# google analytics api limit

Tags: java, google-analytics

I am trying to download number of sessions in Java for time period twice a month using a loop.

Results are imported into a SQL database.

Download in Java is executed here:

```
private static GaData getResults(Analytics analytics, String profileId) throws IOException {
    return analytics.data().ga().get("ga:" + "000000000", //example id
    Var.str_startDate,
    Var.str_endDate,
    "ga:sessions")
    .setSegment("gaid::" + Var.arrayAdvanceSegmentID_traffic[Var.loop_arrayAdvanceSegment_traffic])
    .setMaxResults(100000)
    .execute();
  }
```

Loop should execute code above ten times for ten different segments, but after the seventh loop I get the error messages:

Error: 8
Error: 9

Until seventh round of the loop data is downloaded correctly.

Does anyone know what this error means and why the download for the last two rounds of the loop fails?

Is this maybe due to capping of Google Analytics API traffic?

I can not find any information on these error mesages in Java.

Comment: Had you tried too see how handle those errors? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/errors

Comment: BTW your `setMaxResults` is too high: "The Analytics Core Reporting API returns a maximum of 10,000 rows per request"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer:

In one query maximum of 7 dimensions can be downloaded, according to Core Reporting API - Reference Guide.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference